# Server is not returning the SQL data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a simple blog script in PHP and SQL, on the page where the latest posts need to be displayed everything works fine,  however, I made a page 'comments.php' that will load the comments of the selected post. 
If you click on let's say Post 1, the link generated by PHP would be 'comments.php?id=1'.

This is the code I have on the 'blog.php' page, where everything works fine and post content is displayed correctly:

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$req = $db->query('SELECT id, title, content, DATE_FORMAT(creation, \'%d/%m/%Y at %H:%i\') AS datePosted, user FROM blogpost ORDER BY creation DESC LIMIT 0, 5');
    while($data = $req->fetch()){
      ?>
        <div class="blogpost-container">
          <div class="blogpost-title">

            <?php
                echo htmlspecialchars($data['title']) . " | <em>Posted on ".$data['datePosted']."</em>";
             ?>
          </div>
          <div class="blogpost-content">
            <?php
                echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data['content']));
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="blogpost-user">
            <?php
                echo "Posted by: ".$data['user'].".";
             ?>
           </div>
           <div class="blogpost-comments">
             <a href=<?php echo "'comments.php?id=". $data['id']."'"; ?> >
               Show comments
             </a>
           </div>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
    $req->closeCursor();
 ?>
```

Here, the post load correctly, but once I go on comments.php?id=1 for example, it doesn't show anything. Here's the code from the 'comments.php':

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO('mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8;', 'root', '');
  $req = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content, DATE_FORMAT(creation, \'%d/%m/%Y at %H:%i), user FROM blogpost WHERE id = ?');
  $req->execute(array(
      $_GET['id']
  ));

  $data = $req->fetch();
 ?>
 <div class="blogpost-container">
   <div class="blogpost-title">

     <?php
         echo htmlspecialchars($data['title']) . " | <em>Posted on ".$data['datePosted']."</em>";
      ?>
   </div>
   <div class="blogpost-content">
     <?php
         echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data['content']));
     ?>
   </div>
   <div class="blogpost-user">
     <?php
         echo "Posted by: ".$data['user'].".";
      ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check for any errors and paste it here if you get any

Comment: I am not getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found where I made a mistake. I forgot to add \' at

```
... DATE_FORMAT(creation, \'....\')....
```